# How to Decode selected keys manually and rest with the automatic decoding with swift Decodable?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable, encodable

Here is the code I am using,

```
struct CreatePostResponseModel : Codable{
    var transcodeId:String?
    var id:String = ""
    enum TopLevelCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case _transcode = "_transcode"
        case _transcoder = "_transcoder"
    }
    enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
        case id = "_id"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: TopLevelCodingKeys.self)
        if let transcodeId = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: ._transcode) {
            self.transcodeId = transcodeId
        }else if let transcodeId = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: ._transcoder) {
            self.transcodeId = transcodeId
        }

    }
}
```

Here, `transcodeId` is decided by either `_transcode` or `_transcoder`.
But I want `id` and rest of the keys (not included here) to be automatically decoded. How can I do it ?

Comment: You have to manually decode the other keys as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually parse all the keys once you implement `init(from:)` in the `Codable` type.

```
struct CreatePostResponseModel: Decodable {
    var transcodeId: String?
    var id: String

    enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
        case id, transcode, transcoder
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id) ?? ""
        if let transcodeId = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .transcode) {
            self.transcodeId = transcodeId
        } else if let transcodeId = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .transcoder) {
            self.transcodeId = transcodeId
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code,

1. In case you only want to decode the *JSON*, there is no need to use `Codable`. Using `Decodable` is enough.
2. Using multiple `enums` for `CodingKey` seems unnecessary here. You can use a single `enum CodingKeys`.
3. If the *property name* and the *key name* is an exact match, there is no need to explicitly specify the `rawValue` of that `case` in `enum CodingKeys`. So, there is no requirement of `"_transcode"` and `"_transcoder"` `rawValues` in `TopLevelCodingKeys`.

Apart from all that, you can use `keyDecodingStrategy` as `.convertFromSnakeCase` to handle underscore notation (***snake case notation***), i.e.

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase //here.....
    let model = try decoder.decode(CreatePostResponseModel.self, from: data)
    print(model)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

So, you don't need to explicitly handle all the *snake-case keys*. It'll be handled by the `JSONDecoder` on its own.

Comment: Thanks for reply,  For point 1:  I need encodable as well for vice versa. 2: There was a compile error if I am keeping more keys in CodingKeys and not having corresponding variable. 3: The property name comes from either of two values (_transcoder and _transcode).

Comment: Not exactly, I have to anyways decode all the keys :(

Comment: Yes you've to. Its better you modify the API to give a consistent response.

Comment: Absolutely agree.

Answer (score 1):

This can be one of the good solution for you wherever you want you can add multiple keys for one variable:

```
var transcodeId:String?

public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    do {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        transcodeId =  container.getValueFromAvailableKey(codingKeys: [CodingKeys._transcoder,CodingKeys._transcode])
    } catch {
        print("Error reading config file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol{

    func getValueFromAvailableKey(codingKeys:[CodingKey])-> String?{
         for key in codingKeys{
             for keyPath in self.allKeys{
                 if key.stringValue == keyPath.stringValue{
                    do{ 
                        return try self.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: keyPath)
                    } catch {
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler-generated `init(from:)` is all-or-nothing. You can’t have it decode some keys and “manually” decode others.

One way to use the compiler-generated `init(from:)` is by giving your `struct` **both** of the possible encoded properties, and make `transcodeId` a computed property:

```
struct CreatePostResponseModel: Codable {
    var transcodeId: String? {
        get { _transcode ?? _transcoder }
        set { _transcode = newValue; _transcoder = nil }
    }

    var _transcode: String? = nil
    var _transcoder: String? = nil

    var id: String = “”
    // other properties
}
```